# Issues turning Wordpress' the_post() into a link

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a hard time turning a post in The Loop into a link. Basically I'm trying to make the displayed posts into links. The Loop automatically closes all my `<a>` tags and won't let me turn the content of `the_post()` into one big link.

Here's the problem code. This probably something simple I'm just overlooking.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <a href="#" <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
  <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
  </a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

*Edited to remove extraneous link.
Also, this is not valid HTML, it's just test code for a proof-of-concept piece.

Comment: I'd like to just clear something up... `the_post()` is a function that sets up variables for use with each iteration of a loop, it is not a function that returns a string or some data you can output, it's purely a setter function.. (it does the same as `setup_postdata()`). It's this function that sets up the variables required to call functions like `the_title()`, `the_content()`, etc..

Comment: Correct. I was trying to turn everything pulled from within the_post() into a link, but there was a single extra link inside the_content() in one of the posts I was pulling that was breaking everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your markup is completely invalid. You can not have an `<h3>`, or any other block-level element, inside an `<a>`, and moreover you can't have an `<a>` inside an `<a>`. This is not a Wordpress issue, this is simply nonsense HTML.

Comment: I do recognize that this is invalid HTML, but it works in other cases, such as a link encasing an img/h3/p combination. I'm just trying a proof of concept within a Wordpress loop.

Comment: Also, that inner link wasn't supposed to be in there, fixing it now.

Comment: @Jeff What does the generated HTML look like then?

Comment: There was another inner link in the content being pulled in the_content() from Wordpress that was causing the issue. It looks like it was just a nested link issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid.

Even if you wanted to make the whole thing a link, where is your opening `<a>`? In addition, you are closing one with every iteration.

Post your full code.